# Does Borda count satisfies the participation criterion?

Tags: reference-request, voting-theory, social-choice-theory

The [Borda count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borda_count), or average rank method, is said to satisfies the [participation criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participation_criterion).

This means that this ranking method is free from the "no show paradox".

Do you know any proof of this claim? Can you please link to a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is fairly simple, so I don't know of any work that spells it out (though there might well be).

To satisfy the Participation Criterion, The following situation should be impossible:

1. Voter Anne prefers candidate $A$ over $B$.
2. With all votes tallied, $B$ wins the election.
3. Had Anne not voted, $A$ would have won.

For Borda count, the candidate with the most "points" is elected, where the points of a candidate are simply the sum of the points they get per ballot, in which a better place on the ballot gives more points. This means that with all votes tallied, $B$ has more points, but with Anne's ballot removed, $A$ has more points. This necessarily means that she assigned more points to $B$ than $A$, which is in contradiction with Anne preferring candidate $A$ over $B$.